# Tree insert / remove / print crashes

Tags: c++, tree

I'm trying to implement a tree from an hpp file and I seem to be running into issues with the delete functionality. The logic I am following makes sense, however I cannot seem to figure out why it crashes when I print something out after removing an object.

```
Tree::Tree() {
    root=NULL;
}

void Tree::print() const {
    printinOrder(root);
}

void Tree::printinOrder(Tree::Node* root) const {
    if (root == NULL) return;
    printinOrder(root->left);
    cout<<root->val<<",";
    printinOrder(root->right);
}

Tree::Node::Node(DataType value) {
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
    val = value;
}

bool Tree::tree_ins(Tree::Node* node, Tree::Node* insert_node) {
    if (node-> val == insert_node->val) return false;
    if (insert_node->val > node->val && node-> right == NULL) {
        node->right = insert_node;
        return true;
    }
    if (insert_node->val < node->val && node-> left == NULL) {
        node->left = insert_node;
        return true;
    }
    if (insert_node->val > node->val) return tree_ins(node->right, insert_node);
    if (insert_node->val < node->val) return tree_ins(node->left, insert_node);
}

bool Tree::insert(int val) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new Node(val);
        return true;
    }
    Node* insert_node = new Node(val);
    return tree_ins (root, insert_node);
}

Tree::Node* Tree::getMinValue(Tree::Node* node) {
    if (node->left == NULL) {
        return node;
    }
    return getMinValue(node->left);
}

bool Tree::tree_rem(Tree::Node* test_node, int value) {
    if (test_node == NULL) return false;
    else if (value < test_node-> val) tree_rem (test_node-> left, value);
    else if (value > test_node-> val) tree_rem (test_node-> right, value);
    else {
        if (test_node-> left==NULL && test_node->right == NULL) {
            delete (test_node);
            return true;
        }
        else if (test_node-> left==NULL) {
            test_node->val = (test_node->right)->val;
            test_node = test_node ->right;
            test_node=NULL;
            return true;
        }
        else if (test_node-> right==NULL) {
            test_node->val = (test_node->left)->val;
            test_node = test_node ->left;
            test_node=NULL;
            return true;
        } else {
            Node* minNode = getMinValue(test_node->right);
            test_node->val = minNode->val;
            tree_rem(test_node->right, minNode->val);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

bool Tree::remove(int val) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    Node* temp = root;
    return tree_rem (temp, val);
}
```

Insertion works, printing the tree works. I noticed that after removing an object printing the tree crashes the program, however if I insert something right after removing an object, and then print the tree, it does not crash (but inserts it into the wrong location)

If I run it in this sequence, it crashes:

```
bst->insert(5);
bst->insert(3);
bst->insert(7);
bst->remove(7);
bst->print();
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change a pointer value, it must be passed by reference, so:

```
bool Tree::tree_rem(Tree::Node*& test_node, int value)
```

In your code, all actions on the `test_node` pointer have an effect only inside function, you work with a copy of `test_node`, so  `test_node = test_node->right;` really does nothing with passed argument.

Also, you need to set `test_node` pointer to NULL after deleting.

```
 if (test_node->left == NULL && test_node->right == NULL) {
            delete (test_node);
            test_node = NULL;
            return true;
         }
```

Comment: Tried this, it did not work. I'm already passing a pointer to the function though.

Comment: user2883071, try `test_node = NULL;` fix.

Comment: That fixed it. thank you Dymtro. 2 questions. Since I am passing a pointer value in, why do I have to pass by reference? even if it creates a copy of the pointer value, doesn't that point to the same memory location as root? Second, why should I be setting `test_node` to NULL after? doesn't delete free up the memory and make it available (as opposed to `free()`?

Comment: 1. This quation explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240161/reason-to-pass-a-pointer-by-reference-in-c
2. Becouse you use checking for null in your `printinOrder` : `if (root == NULL) return;`. This check will not work if you do not set NULL manualy. `delete` doesn't do it automatically.