# How can I correctly pass a pointer to a function?

Tags: c++, pointers

I can't seem to pass pointer to memory address. I thought the following code would pass the memory address that `ptr` points at, to my `func()`, then when I print out the address within `func()` it would show the same address as `ptr` did from within `main()`, however that's not what I'm seeing. `p`'s address is different from `ptr`'s address.

How do I correctly pass a pointer to functions?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int* p)
{
    printf("p address: %p\r\n", &p);
}

int main()
{
    int* ptr;
    memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(int));
    printf("ptr address: %p\r\n", &ptr);
    func(ptr);
}
```

Comment: First, `ptr` doesn't point to anything. It is not initialised, and `memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(int));` doesn't make it point to anything in particular. It is an invalid pointer. Note that even copying an invalid pointer is undefined behaviour. Second, you never examine the value of `ptr`. You print the address of `ptr`, and then the address of `p`. They are different objects. Different objects in general have different addresses. Third, `%p` is only good for printing `void*`, and `&ptr` is not `void*`, so this is undefined behaviour again. Fourth, we don't use pointers or `printf` much in C++.

Comment: Not the only problem with the code but you print the pointer like this `printf("p address: %p\r\n", p);`. You should already have a pointer then `&` will give you a pointer to a pointer which is not what you're looking for here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240161/reason-to-pass-a-pointer-by-reference-in-c

Comment: Thanks everyone, it helped me debug my code. I use malloc now to init a pointer, seems to be working, and I fixed pointer at a pointer issue. I think I have to deal with them, since I'm trying to pack up a complex struct to send over a network, not sure what else can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this declaration:

```
void func(int* p)
```

the variable `p` is indeed a copy of `ptr`, and so they have different memory addresses. The same rules apply here as they do for an `int` parameter. There's nothing special about pointers in this context. Don't be confused by the fact that the pointed at values are the same, i.e `*p` and `*ptr` are the same. The objects `p` and `ptr` are still copies of each other, and have different addresses.

If you want the argument `p` to have the same address as `ptr`, accept it by reference:

```
void func(int* &p)
```

Of course, they both still *point* at the same address as well.

Comment: Note: The copying of pointers becomes very important later when you need to pass a pointer into a function to change where it points. This mistake trips up a lot of people writing their first linked list.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I think you are looking for

```
void func(int* p)
{
    printf("%p\n", p);
}

int main()
{
    int something = 0;
    int* ptr = &something;
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
    func(ptr);
}
```

Note there is only one `&` in the whole program when I initialise the pointer in `main`. It's using `&` when it isn't needed that was your main problem I believe.